# AWS EC2 Reserved Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-reserved-instances

I currently have more than 10 EC2 instances with the same type (t2) and the same region (Ohio) and I am checking the best way to save in the monthly bill without losing performance.

I've checked **Reserved Instances (RI)**, but `T2` is only available as shared tenancy (Sharing the Hardware).

My questions are,

- Can that affect the performance of my application deployed on that instance? What happens when the application has more load/requests?
- Are Reserved Instances also working with shared tenancy?
- Does Reserved Instances service create instances or is it possible to buy, ie **10 RI T2** type to apply to my current instances?

Comment: I think there is some confusion on what shared tendency is. You are currently running your 10 instances on ST. Using RI does not change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main Points are,

**Reserved instances are one of the types of purchase options available for EC2 instance to enable you to optimize your costs based on your needs**.

**Tenancy defines how EC2 instances are distributed across physical hardware and obviously it affects pricing. The main thing here, with a tenancy selected(say dedicated), you can also decide your purchase options(either spot or on-demand or reserved)**

So answering your question based on the above statements,

1. *Can that affect the performance of my application deployed on that
   instance? What happens when the application has more load/requests?* No it doesn't, It is totally based on the instance type that you've selected. When application has more load, try to add more instance or change the type of instance.
2. *Are Reserved Instances also working with shared tenancy?*
   Yes, explained above.
3. *Reserved Instancies service is creates instances or it's possible to buy, ie 10 RI T2 type to apply to my current instances?*
   It's just a pricing option.

you can read these two docs for getting a better understanding.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-purchasing-options.html

https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/dedicated-instances/

Answer (score 1):

> Can that affect the performance of my application deployed on that instance? What happens when the application has more load/requests?

No it **can't**. There is no effect.

> Are Reserved Instances also working with shared tenancy?

It does not apply to you. RI is only pricing discount, **not related** to the fact whether you use shared tenancy, dedicated instances.

> Reserved Instancies service is creates instances or it's possible to buy, ie 10 RI T2 type to apply to my current instances?

It does not create new instances. Its just a **pricing discount**.